# How to protect the same resource using both spring-session and spring-security-oauth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-session

I have a requirement to use two kinds of authentication,
for web we @EnableRedisHttpSession and for other consumers like mobile we use @EnableAuthorizationServer with @EnableResourceServer.

suppose we try to protect a controller common to both the authentication mechanisms for e.g /api/v1/test

i have hit a roadblock.
i am only able to use one kind of authentication scheme
if i set @WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter @order(2) and @ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter @order(3) then i can only access the resource via web

and if i set @ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter @order(2) and @WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter @order(3) then only OAuth works.

i am unable to use both the mechanism at the same time.how can we make the two work together, for e.g if the request comes from web use the filter responsible for that and if the request comes from mobile use the appropriate filter. web uses cookies and API Consumers use Authorization : Bearer header.

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sounds very strange. I suggest you to review how REST API is used and why it should be used by browser users. Better to separate web views and REST API, don't mix it.

However, answering your question "can I use two kinds of authentication for some URI at once" - yes, you can.
You need custom `RequestMatcher` that will decide how to route incoming request.

So:

- for "API consumers" - check existence of `Authorization` header
  contains "Bearer"
- for "browser users" - just inverse first rule

Code example:

```java
public abstract class AntPathRequestMatcherWrapper implements RequestMatcher {

    private AntPathRequestMatcher delegate;

    public AntPathRequestMatcherWrapper(String pattern) {
        this.delegate = new AntPathRequestMatcher(pattern);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (precondition(request)) {
            return delegate.matches(request);
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected abstract boolean precondition(HttpServletRequest request);

}
```

1. OAuth2 authentication

```java
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfigurer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcherWrapper("/api/v1/test") {
            @Override
            protected boolean precondition(HttpServletRequest request) {
                return String.valueOf(request.getHeader("Authorization")).contains("Bearer");
            }
        }).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

2. Web authentication

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcherWrapper("/api/v1/test") {
            @Override
            protected boolean precondition(HttpServletRequest request) {
                return !String.valueOf(request.getHeader("Authorization")).contains("Bearer");
            }
        }).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Using this configuration it's possible to use two different authentication types for one URI `/api/v1/test`.

In addition, I highly recommended to read the article about Spring Security architecture by Dave Syer, to understand how does it work:
https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/#_web_security

Comment: i have added a thank you @ https://github.com/aankur/spring-authentication-session-oauth2

Comment: @Ankur you're welcome :) but anyway, it's still a dirty hack

Comment: suppose i have common functionality that can be used with both authentication , should i duplicate the functionality rather than reusing it.